# How do I design the Tx and Rx path using a single antenna without using Tx/Rx switch?

Tags: rf, rfid

I am trying to make a communication system where my module will transmit the commands and the asset tag will reply back (UHF RFID communication (868 MHz).) I will be using an antenna for far field communication. In order to receive the response from the asset tag, a Tx RF should always fall on it as it is a passive tag.
I am using an RF front end IC which has internal PA for power gain in Tx path and LNA in Rx path, but the Tx path and Rx path cannot operate at same time.

I would like to know, in order to operate Tx and Rx at the same time, what type of components can be used? SPDT RF switches will not work as they can only connect to Tx or Rx path at a time.

Comment: What type of RFID? UHF? In which case it is common to use a circulator.

Comment: A circulator or a bidirectional coupler? I am confused/unable to understand if both are different or not?

Comment: Wikipedia will explain the circulator. Since we are talking about this, that suggests you are doing UHF RFID. You might want to state that in your question. LF and HF RFID are totally different, so you want to be specific.

Comment: You can use a duplexer.
PS: Body must be at least 30 characters; you entered 23.

Comment: Circulators and bidirectional couplers perform different functions.  A bidirectional coupler allows you to monitor simultaneously the forward and reverse (reflected) power in a transmission path, which is not what you're trying to accomplish. I would not use a bidirectional coupler for this application.  I'd use a duplexer (as pgibbons suggests) or a circulator.  And if it's possible, I recommend you disable (turn OFF) the LNA's output in the Rx signal path whenever the transceiver is transmitting.

Answer (score 1):

In an ideal world, a 4-port directional coupler would do the trick. A directional coupler is similar to a "hybrid coil" used to allow bidirectional communication in analog telephone lines.

I have copied the symbol for a 4-port directional coupler from [Microwaves101](https://www.microwaves101.com/encyclopedias/directional-couplers)

[image]

How it works is you would connect your transmitter to port 1, your antenna to port 2, a resistor to port 3, and the receiver to port 4.

The value of the resistor should be the impedance of the transmission line used to connect the components together.

Again, in an ideal world, half the signal applied to port 1 will be sent to the antenna on port 2, and half the signal power will be dissipated in the resistor across port 3. Half the signal returned from the tag, through the antenna will arrive at port 4, and half at port 1.

If everything works ideally, although you need to apply twice the power, you can transmit and receive simultaneously, and none of the transmitted signal will be sent to the receiver. However, in practice, you will get transmitted signal at the receiver because matching of the transmission line between the antenna and the coupler will be imperfect, as will be the matching between the resistor at port three and the coupler.

Given that you will receive *some* of the transmitted signal at the receiver, (in the telephony world this would be called near-end cross-talk), the question becomes whether or not the received signal is sufficiently strong in relation to the cross-talk, that you may successfully decode it.

My guess is that it will take a non-trivial amount of effort to get things right.

Answer (score -2):

I want to propose a second answer, it might not work.
Use 3 antennas, the middle one for RX and have it perfectly centered between the outer 2 antennas which are used for TX and their signal will cancel at the RX antenna.

Comment: No, they won't.  Just the opposite, the signals from the two antennas will add in phase.  Why do you think they will cancel?

Comment: Oh yeah you're right that wouldn't work. I don't know why my duplexer answer was deleted, I'll post it again.

Comment: @pgibbons Answers need to be full and complete. You could have explained why and how a duplexer would be good for the OPs application but instead you wrote "use a duplexer". It was flagged by the system for low quality (and I agree). Please read this: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score -2):

You can use a duplexer.
Further explanation:
A duplexer is an electronic device that allows bi-directional (duplex) communication over a single path.

Comment: Voltage Spike you are killing me! You deleted my answer twice because I didn't explain enough. Not every answer needs a bunch of explaining! The guy can simply go on the web and look up duplexer and learn all about it... why do I have to do that???

Comment: whether one uses duplexer or two separate IC's for Tx and Rx, the main concern was how to make sure that the Tx is not interfering with Rx, while in Rx mode. For UHF RFID, Rx is only possible when there is a Tx being sent out.

Comment: @pgibbons you *don't* have to do that, you also have the option of not polluting SE with worthless crap to begin with. Especially since just looking up "duplexer" will mostly find devices that are *completely unsuitable* for this problem.

Comment: @hobbs It is a complete coincidence that I'm here today to see your message. I have actually stopped contributing to all of stackexchange because of people like you and I'm glad about it. Good riddance ;)

Comment: @hobbs "Especially since just looking up "duplexer" will mostly find devices that are completely unsuitable for this problem."
Yep, here you are expected to spoon-feed the answers. People here asking questions are not necessarily capable of doing further research on subjects. Pointing someone in the right direction works in real life but not on here, that's why I stopped contributing. It's your loss because I know a lot of answers. Saves me the time so thanks.